# JwPlayer load next playlist item instead of skipping to the next item?

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer, playlist

Is there a way to load next item in the play-list instead of switching to the next?
So I am using `jwplayer().playlistNext();`, the problem with that is that it takes an extra ~ 2 sec. The video stops, then waits, the loads and starts playing... when using a load function it loads and starts immediately. How to combine or just make an instant switching?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid pre-loading playlist items is not possible in the JW Player.